# Windows Task Scheduler to monitor Microsoft SQL Server table/data modification (INSERT, UPDATE)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, scheduler

Is there a way to run a task via Windows Task Scheduler triggered by Microsoft SQL Server table or view modification (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`)?

I.e. can Windows Task Scheduler monitor Microsoft SQL Server data changes?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler is designed to **run tasks** (programs etc.) at specific, given times.... it's not designed to *monitor* **anything** .... Please try to explain what you're **really** trying to do / achieve. This is too unclear as of yet ....

Comment: Why Task Scheduler and not SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: I will try to be more specific. I need to run a python script outside of Microsoft SQL Server. The script should be started after modification or update of a table in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about windows task scheduler, but you may want to look at the built in Change Data Capture functionality, which allows you to write to a set of CDC tables when changes are made to data.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx